# CSS Style not loading for the second container in NextJS

Tags: css, next.js

I have a two basic div containers and I am trying to apply some styles to it. I do import my CSS styles from a separate .module.css file and the first style gets picked up in the className property, when assigned. However, the same thing is not working for the second div. The css property for class 'sales' is not being picked up

dashboard.js

```
import HomeSalesmanStyles from '../../../styles/SalesmanHome.module.css';

const HomeSalesman = ({name}) => {
  return(
    <>
      <div className={HomeSalesmanStyles.container}>
        <h4>
          Hello, {name}  
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div className={HomeSalesmanStyles.sales}>
          Hello
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default HomeSalesman;
```

SalesmanHome.module.css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
};
.sales {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Any ideas where the issue is?

----------- Edit ------------
The issue was wrong css module name import! After correcting to the right file, everything works.

Comment: Is the CSS file named `SalesmanDashboard.module.css` or `SalesmanHome.module.css`? You're using names in your question.

Comment: @juliomalves Nice catch! I totally missed it! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a syntax error in the CSS: adding a semicolon after a rule is invalid.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
} /* <- no semicolon */
.sales {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>
    Hello, {name}  
  </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="sales">
      Hello
  </div>
```

Comment: My bad, I corrected the semicolon and still not working..